# Timer gets faster on next calls wp8.1

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone-8.1, countdown

i have a countdown timer like this:

```
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private int _countdown;

    private void initialize_timer()
   {

       _countdown = 100;
       _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
       _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
       _timer.Tick += (s, e) => Tick();
       _timer.Start();
   }
   private void Tick()
   {
       _countdown--;
       if (_countdown == 0)
       {
           _timer.Stop();
       }

       TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_countdown);
       string str = time.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
       RemainingTime.Text = str;
   }
```

it works fine until i call initialize_timer() again. the timer gets faster on every call. note that _countdown will be a dynamic value based on a future time so it will change on each call.

Comment: `the timer gets faster` or you get many `Tick()` s including the old ones ?

Comment: i dont know. i see all seconds but changing faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `initialize_timer()`, you create a new `Timer` but your old `Timer` is still there and ticking. Just remove the lines

```
_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
_timer.Tick += (s, e) => Tick();
```

and you'll be OK.

Comment: when i remove it _timer becomes null and crashes

Comment: I think what he meant was `if (_timer == null) _timer = new DispatchTimer();`, which initializes it once; but there are more changes needed.

Comment: @Petesh thanks, you're right, actually the `initialize_timer` is expected to be run only once. BTW, I edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: i changed the code to this:
    if (_timer==null){_timer = new DispatcherTimer(); _timer.Tick += (s, e) => Tick();}